# Android change owner group of a file created by app

Tags: android, linux, file, permissions

In my android app I am downloading a file and writing it to a location in the storage. I want to change the owner group of this file as soon as I am done writing the file.
Does android provide a way to accomplish this ?
I am using `java.io.File` to perform the write to the destination location.

I have read about using `java.nio.file.Files.getFileAttributeView().setGroup()` but that package is not available to me for some reason. Is there any alternative to this ?

Comment: "I want to change the owner group of this file as soon as I am done writing the file" -- why? What problem are you trying to solve? "Does android provide a way to accomplish this ?" -- no, which is why I asked the preceding questions. "but that package is not available to me for some reason" -- the Android SDK does not contain everything from Java SE. In particular, file ownership is purely the responsibility of the OS; apps do not get a vote in how that is handled.

Comment: I can explain the use-case : Consider there is a custom ROM in which another app will read this file. The app will have access to this file only if the owner group of the file is set to a specific group. From my point of view the app already has the modifications to look for the file at a particular location. My job is to download the file and write to that location and set the owner group that would allow the app to read that file.

Comment: If your custom ROM has the `chown` command-line utility, you could look to run it from your app. Or, you could look into using the NDK. Bear in mind that you may not have the rights to change the ownership of the file, in which case you're now looking at needing superuser privileges.